# Textbox to update Gridview columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, textbox

I have a Gridview. My Gridview contains 4 columns: dates, room id, quantity, price for the number of rooms available at any given period selected from a calendar. For my quantity and price I want to allow my user the option of having the textbox field they have entered quantity on for an arrow to appear for the user to click to apply the same quantity across all dates and the same option for price.  I have looked everywhere but most common answers are for finding bulk update of Gridviews or displaying into a textbox. any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have a small solution for you:

Here is the data I have created a dummy:

```
        DataTable dtGridView = new DataTable();
        //dates, room id, quantity, price
        dtGridView.Columns.Add("dates", typeof(string));
        dtGridView.Columns.Add("room_id", typeof(int));
        dtGridView.Columns.Add("quantity", typeof(int));
        dtGridView.Columns.Add("price", typeof(double));

        dtGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/28/2014", 1, 11, 150 });
        dtGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/27/2014", 1, 5, 160 });
        dtGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/21/2014", 2, 6, 300 });
        dtGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3/20/2014", 3, 9, 70 });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtGridView;
```

Here is a dummy of your datagridview with data, a textbox and a button as following:
[image]

Now on your button click event you can write the following code which updates all price field according to the price entered in textbox.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GET UPDATING PRICE FROM TEXTBOX
        double _price = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

        //LOOP ON DATAGRIDVIEW
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["price"].Value = _price;
        }
    }
```

Now run your program and try entering updating price in text box and click the button..    Hope this helps you....  :)